# JS удаление элемента из local storage

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Помогите с реализацией функционала.
Задача: есть массив элементов в localstorage. Их нужно вывести и напротив каждого элемента сделать ссылку удаление соответствующего элемента из localstorage и из DOM'a.

Использую библиотеку breeze (cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/breezejs/1.4.11/breeze.min.js) для удобной работы с localstorage, но возникают проблемы с удалением.

По каким то причинам удаляется только один элемент. Кто может посмотрите плз:
http://jsfiddle.net/2D6J5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@lightcyber](/users/6762/lightcyber)](/users/6762/lightcyber), вы вместо удаления одного конкретного элемента из списка, полностью заменяете его содержимое, заново заполняя элементами. При этом не назначаете на  добавленные элементы обработчик клика. Иными словами, после выполнения вашей функции в списке не остается ни одного элемента с этим обработчиком.

Есть несколько вариантов решения для вашей версии jQuery.
**[Вот один из них, с минимальным вмешательством в ваш код](http://jsfiddle.net/2D6J5/4/)**:

```
// Привязываем обработчик события на контейнер, содержащий искомые элементы
$("#listCMP").bind('click', '.zingayaClosel', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    // Проверяем, что кликнули именно по ссылке удаления
    if (target.hasClass('zingayaClosel')) {
        removefromCMPlist($(e.target).attr('title'));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Выручили.